# How to test tensorflow cifar10 cnn tutorial model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

After training and evaluating the cifar10 dataset from the tensorflow [tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html), how could one test it with sample images?

I could train and evaluate the [Imagenet tutorial from the caffe machine-learning framework](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) and it was relatively easy to use the trained model on custom applications using the python API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't 100% the answer to the question, but it's a similar way of solving it, based on a MNIST NN training example suggested in the comments to the question.

Based on the TensorFlow begginer MNIST tutorial, and thanks to [this tutorial](http://opensourc.es/blog/tensorflow-mnist), this is a way of training and using your Neural Network with custom data.

Please note that similar should be done for tutorials such as the CIFAR10, as @Yaroslav Bulatov mentioned in the comments.

```
import input_data
import datetime
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from random import randint


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,10])

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#Train our model
iter = 1000
for i in range(iter):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

#Evaluationg our model:
correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))
print "Accuracy: ", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})

#1: Using our model to classify a random MNIST image from the original test set:
num = randint(0, mnist.test.images.shape[0])
img = mnist.test.images[num]

classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [img]})
'''
#Uncomment this part if you want to plot the classified image.
plt.imshow(img.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
'''
print 'Neural Network predicted', classification[0]
print 'Real label is:', np.argmax(mnist.test.labels[num])


#2: Using our model to classify MNIST digit from a custom image:

# create an an array where we can store 1 picture
images = np.zeros((1,784))
# and the correct values
correct_vals = np.zeros((1,10))

# read the image
gray = cv2.imread("my_digit.png", 0 ) #0=cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE #must be .png!

# rescale it
gray = cv2.resize(255-gray, (28, 28))

# save the processed images
cv2.imwrite("my_grayscale_digit.png", gray)
"""
all images in the training set have an range from 0-1
and not from 0-255 so we divide our flatten images
(a one dimensional vector with our 784 pixels)
to use the same 0-1 based range
"""
flatten = gray.flatten() / 255.0
"""
we need to store the flatten image and generate
the correct_vals array
correct_val for a digit (9) would be
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
"""
images[0] = flatten


my_classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [images[0]]})

"""
we want to run the prediction and the accuracy function
using our generated arrays (images and correct_vals)
"""
print 'Neural Network predicted', my_classification[0], "for your digit"
```

For further image conditioning (digits should be completely dark in a white background) and better NN training (accuracy>91%) please check the Advanced MNIST tutorial from TensorFlow or the 2nd tutorial i've mentioned.

Comment: Please also add line of code for "How to save and load already trained model"

Answer (score 3):

I recommend taking a look at the [basic MNIST tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) on the TensorFlow website. It looks like you define some function that generates the type of output that you want, and then run your session, passing it this evaluation function (`correct_prediction` below), and a dictionary containing whatever arguments you require (`x` and `y_` below).

If you have defined and trained some network that takes an input `x`, generates a response `y` based on your inputs, and you know your expected responses for your testing set `y_`, you may be able to print out every response to your testing set with something like:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(y, y_)  % Check whether your prediction is correct
print(sess.run(correct_prediction, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_: test_labels}))
```

This is just a modification of what is done in the tutorial, where instead of trying to print each response, they determine the percent of correct responses. Also note that the tutorial uses *one-hot vectors* for the prediction `y` and actual value `y_`, so in order to return the associated numeral, they have to find which index of these vectors are equal to one with `tf.argmax(y, 1)`.

**Edit**

In general, if you define something in your graph, you can output it later when you run your graph. Say you define something that determines the result of the softmax function on your output logits as:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  ...
  prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  ...
```

then you can output this at run time with:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  ...
  feed_dict = { ... }  # define your feed dictionary
  pred = sess.run([prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  # do stuff with your prediction vector
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I could understand their operations to "determine the percent of correct responses" to the mnist test data and labels. 
     My doubt now is how to evaluate one single digit and get it's classification. I guess one of the procedures would also be convert my data to a format that is compatible with tensorflow?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to convert your images into numpy array of [height, width, depth] values 0..255 and feed that array in. See the format here: https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py

Comment: can you include how to output y_? Right now you are inputting the test labels and basically returning how often they are correct. What if you want to input a test image and output the associated softmax y_ vector directly?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 I added some more detail to my answer that might help.

Answer (score 3):

The below example is not for the mnist tutorial, but a simple XOR example. Note the `train()` and `test()` methods. All that we declare & keep globally are the weights, biases, and session. In the test method we redefine the shape of the input and reuse the same weights & biases (and session) that we refined in training.

```
import tensorflow as tf

#parameters for the net
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[2,2], minval=-1, maxval=1, name='weights1'))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[2,1], minval=-1, maxval=1, name='weights2'))

#biases
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]), name='bias1')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='bias2')

#tensorflow session
sess = tf.Session()


def train():

    #placeholders for the traning inputs (4 inputs with 2 features each) and outputs (4 outputs which have a value of 0 or 1)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [4, 2], name='x-inputs')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [4, 1], name='y-inputs')

    #set up the model calculations
    temp = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)
    output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(temp, w2) + b2)

    #cost function is avg error over training samples
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(((y * tf.log(output)) + ((1 - y) * tf.log(1.0 - output))) * -1)

    #training step is gradient descent
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

    #declare training data
    training_x = [[0,1], [0,0], [1,0], [1,1]]
    training_y = [[1], [0], [1], [0]]

    #init session
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    #training
    for i in range(100000):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:training_x, y:training_y})

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print (i, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x:training_x, y:training_y}))

    print '\ntraining done\n'


def test(inputs):
    #redefine the shape of the input to a single unit with 2 features
    xtest = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 2], name='x-inputs')

    #redefine the model in terms of that new input shape
    temp = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(xtest, w1) + b1)
    output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(temp, w2) + b2)

    print (inputs, sess.run(output, feed_dict={xtest:[inputs]})[0, 0] >= 0.5)


train()

test([0,1])
test([0,0])
test([1,1])
test([1,0])
```